# Reuse methods containing same properties but different lambda where clause condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

Here's the sample scenario, I have 3 different methods with different parameters but the results are the same returning list of a property class.

Here are my codes:

```
// My Model class:
public class Users{ 
   public string Name{ get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }
   public string Location { get; set; }
}

// My Vm class:
public class UserVm { 
   public string Name{ get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }
   public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my lambda queries

```
// by name
public IEnumerable<UserVm> GetUsersByName (string name){
      return db.Users.Where(x=>x.Name == name).Select(users=>new UserVm{
          Name = users.Name,
          Age = users.Age,
          Location = users.Location
      }).Tolist();
}

// by location
public IEnumerable<UserVm> GetUsersByAge (int age){
      return db.Users.Where(x=>x.Age == age).Select(users=>new UserVm{
          Name = users.Name,
          Age = users.Age,
          Location = users.Location
      }).Tolist();
}

// by age
public IEnumerable<UserVm> GetUsersByLocation (string location){
      return db.Users.Where(x=>x.Location== location).Select(users=>new UserVm{
          Name = users.Name,
          Age = users.Age,
          Location = users.Location
      }).Tolist();
}
```

As you notice, all of them returns the same result in view model. Is there a way like I can reuse those redundant codes? Like I'll put these codes

```
return db.Users.Where(x=>x.Location== location).Select(users=>new Users{
          Name = users.Name,
          Age = users.Age,
          Location = users.Location
      }).Tolist();
```

In one method but their where clauses are different in every method that calls the main method?

Comment: `GetUsersBy(Func<UserVm, bool> where)`, e.g. `GetUsersBy(u => u.Age == 50)`

Comment: You like writing a Constructor for your Users model class that takes in a `db.user` and sets the properties from that?

Comment: @ntohl I already updated. Yes it should be UserVm :)

Comment: My advice would be to avoid being too generic. By using different method signatures, you know exactly what you are doing, and you avoid automagic things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple thing you can do is to move the UserVm object creation in an Extension Method, and you will not repeat the objects initialization anymore.

```
public static class UsersExtensionMethods
{
    public static UserVm ToVm(this User user)
    {
        return new UserVm
        {
            Name = user.Name,
            Age = user.Age,
            Location = user.Location
        };
    }
}

// by name
public IEnumerable<UserVm> GetUsersByName (string name){
      return db.Users.Where(x=>x.Name == name).Select(u => u.ToVm()).Tolist();
}

// by age
public IEnumerable<UserVm> GetUsersByAge (int age){
      return db.Users.Where(x=>x.Age == age).Select(u => u.ToVm()).Tolist();
}

// by age
public IEnumerable<UserVm> GetUsersByLocation (string location){
      return db.Users.Where(x=>x.Location== location).Select(u => u.ToVm()).Tolist();
}
```

Comment: Your extension method connects the model to the viewModel. I'm not an MVVM expert but the way I understand it the ViewModel should be aware of the Model, but not the other way around - a Model should not be aware of the ViewModel. Am I wrong?

Comment: That's the beauty. Because it is an extension method, it can even stay in the UI layer. The Domain (Model) will have no clue or reference about the Vm

Comment: The way I see it, it should stay in the ViewModel layer - so what makes it better than having a constructor in the ViewModel class that accepts an instance of a Model? (I'm not giving you a hard time here, I'm really asking since I'm quite new to MVVM)

Comment: No probs. Constructor parameters are normally bad practice, because you get issues when serializing / deserializing the object. I like to use ExtensionMethods, because, this way, i decouple the Vm from the Model object, and keep the logic (construction) in one place. And, extension methods can exist anywhere in the project, as long as the "layer" they exist have access to both `Person` and `PersonVm`. I normally have a  DtoExtensionMethods which exists in the `UI layer`, and where i generate all the Dto (Vms), based on the Model objects. And, there is no reference between them two

Comment: @ZoharPeled No probs. or it is a too long comment to bother replying :D

Comment: @Catalin So, I try to create a folder with a name of "ExtensionMethods" wherein inside that folder contains class for each extension method. Do you think it is good practice? :)

Comment: @jsonGPPD Yes, that looks ok. You can have a folder `ExtensionMethods`, and inside you create a class for each `Model`, like `UserExtensionMethods`, `CompanyExtensionMethods` etc. Inside each class, you define the extension methods for the specific models. Just FYI, you can have unlimited `ExtensionMethods` for the same `Models`, and they can be saved in different libraries. It all depends on your application structure / logic, on how you want to group / split them. In a normal situation, one ExtensionMethods class per Model is enaugh

Comment: Oh thank you for that tip @Catalin. I'm just having a problem in this line of code `.Select(u => u.ToVm())` When I use u=>u. it only shows the properties not the name of the extensionmethod that I'm trying to call based on your sample.

Comment: @jsonGPPD you need to import the extension method namespace to have access to it. `using MyApplication.ExtensionMethods;`

Comment: Yeah even I already have it, it still doesn't ref. but only properties. @Catalin

Comment: @Catalin It's working now. I put the static. By the way, can you explain why you used static there? for class and for extension method? :)

Comment: make sure your ExtensionMethod syntax is correct. Needs to be static, and needs to have `this` keyword

Comment: @jsonGPPD This is the Extension method syntax. Needs to be `static`, and needs to have `this` keyword.

Comment: @jsonGPPD Hmm...it shouldn't. If you have `this`, you can use the method from the object instance directly. Eg: `person.ToVm()`

Comment: Thank you for that tip. I can able to work it even without `this` I don't know why. I can also access it directly using object instance even without this from the constructor of the extension method. @Catalin

Answer (score 6):

Simply pass the lambda expression to your query as a `Func<Users, bool>`:

```
public IEnumerable<UserVm> GetUsers(Func<Users, bool> predicate)
{
      return db.Users.Where(predicate).Select(users=>new UserVm
      {
          Name = users.Name,
          Age = users.Age,
          Location = users.Location
      });
}
```

Also note I've removed the `ToList()` from your original code since you are returning `IEnumerable` anyway.

And you use it like this:

```
// To get all users under a specific age
var usersVm = GetUsers(u => u.Age < age);

// To get all users with a specific name
var usersVm = GetUsers(u => u.name == name);
```

BTW: I like to have a constructor in the ViewModel class that get's an instance of the Model class, so I would probably write it like this:

```
public class UserVm { 
   public UserVm (Users model)
   {
       Name = model.Name;
       Age = model.Age;
       Location = model.Location;
   }
   public string Name{ get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }
   public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

And then your `GetUsers` method would look like this:

```
public IEnumerable<UserVm> GetUsers(Func<Users, bool> predicate)
{
      return db.Users.Where(predicate).Select(user => 
          new UserVm(user));
}
```

Comment: Ha, I added a comment for the ctor in the question aswell **stronk arm**

Comment: @Nerdintraining'questionmark' Well, great minds.... (Though I have to admit my favorite spin on that phrase is "Twisted minds...")

Comment: :D
My mind is far from great, so twisted fits muchas betteros

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helps :) Thank you for the new learning

Comment: Glad to help ;-)

Comment: By the way, what does `Func<Users, bool>` means? @ZoharPeled

Comment: @ZoharPeled I'm having an issue now. return `db.Users.Where(predicate).Select(users=>new UserVm
      {
          Name = users.Name,
          Age = users.Age,
          Location = users.Location
      });` I tried to put `Include`, since suppose Users has a relationship with other models, but I can't find any Include extension there.

Comment: [`Func<Users, bool>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netframework-4.7.1) is a delegate for a method that accepts `Users` and returns a `bool`. I don't know what `Include` is.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new method :

```
public List<Users> GetUsers(object vmData)
{
   vmData.Select(users=>new Users{
          Name = users.Name,
          Age = users.Age,
          Location = users.Location
      }).Tolist();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make different extension methods for your filtering.

```
public static IEnumerable<UserVm> FilterByName(this IEnumerable<UserVm> query, string name)
{
    return query.Where(x => x.Name == name);
}
```

and convertion to the `Users` object:

```
public static IEnumerable<Users> ToUsers(this IEnumerable<UserVm> query)
{
    return query.Select(users => new Users{
        Name = users.Name,
        Age = users.Age, 
        Location = users.Location
    });
}
```

Which allows you to call it as such:

```
var usersA = db.Users.FilterByName("A").ToUsers().ToList();
```

An example of this can be found in this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EEgZNt).